# Add verb to Word vocabulary so Word stops claiming sentence is fragment?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

I'm working with Word for Mac, version 14.3.9 (131030). The same problem exists for Word on my PC, like Word 2013 and Word 2010.

Word has flagged the following sentence as a fragment:

> The adversary phishes the user to gain access to a key.

[image]

The whole sentence is underlined. When I select *"phishes"*, the grammar context menu is displayed. The grammar context menu offers ***Ignore*** and ***Grammar***.

How do I add the word *"phish"* (or *"phishes"*) to Word's vocabulary, and specify that its a verb?

To be clear, I'm not interested in "ignoring" it once. I'm interested in fixing it so Word does not annoy me in the future for related sentences.

---

Here are some related articles, which don't discuss how to add a verb to Word's vocabulary.

- [Frequently asked questions about grammar proofing in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290943)
- [Select grammar and writing style options](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Select-grammar-and-writing-style-options-86dd1e89-cfb5-4405-94df-48c284af9dbd)
- [How to Use Microsoft Word to Find Passive Verb Forms](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-microsoft-word-passive-verb-forms-75444.html)

Comment: Well, phishing is the only variant that is actually a word.

Comment: I'm just saying it's slang, and maybe not the best word to use, especially if this is some sort of report.

Comment: Also, this was the first result of a Google search: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322198

Comment: So, you add the word to the dictionary, but it doesn't work permanently?

Comment: AFAIK you can add it to your custom dictionary but there's no way to specify what part of speech it is.

Comment: @Karan - thanks. I tried adding it to the custom dictionary. But the custom dictionary is too limited. It does not understand stems (like *phish* in *phishing*), and it does not understand how its supposed to be used in a grammar (like its a verb in the English labguage).

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7rYhE.jpg) is the best you can do when it comes to modifying the grammar checking rules.